# Laravel - Wrong result when use same reference after call get method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$queryBody = DB::table("tableA")->where("columnA", true)->where('columnC', true)->select(DB::raw('SUM(columnD)'));

$resultA = $queryBody->where('columnB', 'A')->get();
$resultB = $queryBody->where('columnB', 'B')->get();
$resultC = $queryBody->where('columnB', 'C')->get();
```

This is how I wrote code and I'm expecting difference result each other. However, `$resultA` works fine but others are wrong. Please let me know why it's not working as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the `Builder` is going to be used by reference and not duplicated, therefore, each query will have the constraints from the last one.

The easiest to get around this is to use `clone`:

```
$queryBody = DB::table("tableA")->select(DB::raw('SUM(columnA)'));

$resultA = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'A')->get();
$resultB = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'B')->get();
$resultC = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'C')->get();
```

---

Also, I assume that the queries in your question are just examples but Laravel does come with a [sum()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#aggregates) method for the query builder so you could do:

```
$queryBody = DB::table("tableA");

$resultA = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'A')->sum('columnA');
$resultB = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'B')->sum('columnA');
$resultC = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'C')->sum('columnA');
```

I have still used the `$queryBody` in the above example but if this was your actual query I would simply inline the `DB::table("tableA")` and remove `$queryBody` entirely i.e.
 `$resultA = DB::table("tableA")->where('columnB', 'A')->sum('columnA');`

---

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question you can either do:

```
$queryBody = DB::table("tableA")->where("columnA", true)->where('columnC', true)->select(DB::raw('SUM(columnD)'));

$resultA = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'A')->get();
$resultB = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'B')->get();
$resultC = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'C')->get();
```

*Change is `(clone $queryBody)`*

OR

```
$queryBody = DB::table("tableA")->where("columnA", true)->where('columnC', true);

$resultA = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'A')->sum('columnD');
$resultB = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'B')->sum('columnD');
$resultC = (clone $queryBody)->where('columnB', 'C')->sum('columnD');
```

This is simply removing `->select(DB::raw('SUM(columnD)'))` from the base query and using Laravel's `sum()` method. This will give you just the value rather than a `Collection` with the value in it.

Comment: Thanks for quick comment. I've just updated my question. there are many `where ` closure. So if I use inline style as you wrote, then I need to write duplicated conditions again?

Comment: @AlexandrBiship In that case you can use either example. You're essentially just removing `->select(DB::raw('SUM(columnD)'))` from the `$queryBody` and changing `get()` to `->sum('columnD')`.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship I'll update my answer to show you what I mean. Just FYI, you don't need to use `sum()` if you don't want to. I just wanted to let you know that there is an alternative but only use it if it makes sense to.

Comment: Thanks. actually query which I need to use is very complex. so I need to remove duplicated conditions as possible. I like clone and that makes sense to me. but not sure it's the best way.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship Whichever one makes works and makes sense to you. The main point of my answer to take away is using `clone`. If it helps, for now just ignore the `sum()` bit. I only really added that in as an FYI, it is in no way something you *need* to do. In future posts I would definitely recommend using your actual code as the example for your question rather than a simplified version as it can lead to a bit of confusion in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

try this as when you fetch $querybody for resultB it became  $resultA-

```
$resultA = DB::table("tableA")->select(DB::raw('SUM(columnA)'))->where('columnB', 'A')->get();
$resultB = DB::table("tableA")->select(DB::raw('SUM(columnA)'))->where('columnB', 'B')->get();
$resultC = DB::table("tableA")->select(DB::raw('SUM(columnA)'))->where('columnB', 'C')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$resultA = TableA::select(DB::raw('SUM(columnA)'))->where('columnB', 'A')->get();
$resultB = TableA::select(DB::raw('SUM(columnA)'))->where('columnB', 'B')->get();
$resultC = TableA::select(DB::raw('SUM(columnA)'))->where('columnB', 'C')->get();
```

Try this one as eloquent.